# Issue with Track Changes on Word when using Drawing

Tags: ms-word, drawing

First and foremost if this question is not for this forum please disregard.

Practically the following is the issue:

When one writes with the digital pen (using Draw - Pens) and track changes is with “All Markup” this is fine. The writing is displayed:

[image: All Markup]

The same drawing then vanishes when track changes is with “No Markup”.

[image: No Markup]

I am using Office 2019 Home and Business 2019. I also tried this on an Office 365 version and the same outcome was noted.

Is this a bug? Or is it meant to work like this?

Thank you for your time to review this issue.